# How to change text where depends on many select option on Blade Laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-blade

I'm making website using Laravel, so the web is for selling the cow meat.

I Have 3 Select Option :

First is "qty" where qty is contains pcs option, like price/pcs

Second one is "grade" for the grade of the cow meat

The last one is "bobot" or you can call it *Weight*

Here's my code :

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {

    var optarray = $("#bobot").children('option').map(function() {
        return {
            "value": this.value,
            "option": "<option value='" + this.value + "'>" + this.text + "</option>"
        }
    })

    $("#grade").change(function() {
        $("#bobot").children('option').remove();
        var addoptarr = [];
        for (i = 0; i < optarray.length; i++) {
            if (optarray[i].value.indexOf($(this).val()) > -1) {
                addoptarr.push(optarray[i].option);
            }
        }
        $("#bobot").html(addoptarr.join(''));  

        $('#bobot').change(function() {
            $('p[id^="bobot-harga-"]').hide();
            var selectedOptionVal = $(this).val();
            $('#bobot-harga-' + selectedOptionVal).show();
        }).change();   

    }).change();
})
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<p id="bobot-harga-A-265">Rp 17,900,000</p>
<p id="bobot-harga-B-340">Rp 23,000,000</p>
<p id="bobot-harga-C-400">Rp 27,400,000</p>
<p id="bobot-harga-D-520">Rp 35,700,000</p>
<p id="bobot-harga-E-680_UP">Rp 46,600,000</p>

<select name="grade" id="grade">
  <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="B">B</option>
  <option value="C">C</option>
  <option value="D">D</option>
  <option value="E">E</option>
</select>

<select name="bobot" id="bobot">
  <option value="A-265">-265</option>
  <option value="B-340">-340</option>
  <option value="C-400">-400</option>
  <option value="D-520">-520</option>
  <option value="E-680_UP">-680 UP</option>
</select>

<select name="qty" id="qty">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
</select> 
</body>
</html>
```

For running when i chose grade option, it's shows bobot and price as i want, but.. the problem is if i want to change the qty of the price.

What am i expecting is if i chose qty option 1, it shows default price of the bobot (Note : One bobot have their own price). If i chose qty option 2, it will multiplication the price by 2, and if i change bobot or grade.. i want it change it back to default, same as qty when i previously chose 2, 3, or 5, when i chose 1 will shows correctly

Help, and thanks

Comment: Hi Mirza and welcome to SO. Please provide the *rendered* HTML and create a runnable snippet (look for the `<>` icon in the question editor) to help create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which we can run and test.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier Already insert the snippet, help me find the solution please

Comment: Out of curiosity: why do you have two separate fields for `grade` and `bobot`, when it could just be one field - if `grade` changes, then `bobot` changes with it. It feels like this is just a work in progress, but maybe you could clarify on how this was intended?